# Static route issue on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, route

There's a virtual machine with Windows Server 2008 R2 installed. There are two NICs connected to it: PROD & BUP. The BUP interface is configured without default gateway. After adding static route with `/p` switch, it appears in routing table but traffic still goes through default gateway if you run `tracert`.

I've even tried to add `IF` parameter but the same thing, doesn't work.
Machine hasn't been restarted yet.

What is interesting, there is another Windows Server 2008 R2 machine with such static route and BUP interface's IP-address in the same subnet and everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this on Windows 2008 R2 a few times, where the `route add /p` simply doesn't stick. Use `netsh` with the ipv4 context switch instead.

Let's say your local backup destination net is `192.168.30.0/24`. Use netsh like this:

`netsh ipv4 add persistentroute 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0 "BUP"`

Where: `192.168.30.0` is the destination net, `255.255.255.0` is the destination subnet mask and `"BUP"` is the name of the interface you wish to use

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't work either. Wanna try deleting all static routes, restarting machine & then re-adding routes once again.
Anyway, thx for good suggestion.

Comment: Got one more idea - to disable PROD lan, but haven't done that yet.

Comment: I'd rather try to remove the route, disabling and then enabling the backup interface and then adding it again

Comment: This has been already done several times, no success.

Comment: Even more: I've tried deleting virtual NIC and then re-adding it - still doesn't work :(.

Comment: Eventually the issue has been solved.
The problem was in wrong VLAN. 
BUP-if was simply joined to the wrong vlan.