# Why isn't my static route applying?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, routing

I'm migrating one of my services to a new public facing IP and I'm at a loss as to why the recently added route isn't functioning. This is a Server 2008 R2 box. I've covered several other questions - notably [Windows static route not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/571074/windows-static-route-not-working) and [Static route issue on Windows Server 2008 R2](https://serverfault.com/questions/345550/static-route-issue-on-windows-server-2008-r2) - but I also checked a bunch of other resources as well.

For the time being I'm trying to cut only traffic to my one test source IP.

```
route -p add 11.11.121.110 mask 255.255.255.255 172.125.121.1 if 22 metric 1
```

The interface ID is good on this description. The routing table looks good as well.

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.51.1     192.168.51.5    266
   11.11.121.110  255.255.255.255    172.125.121.1   172.22.125.187     11
    100.100.100.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.51.1     192.168.51.5     11
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     172.22.125.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    172.22.125.187    266
   172.22.125.187  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.22.125.187    266
   172.22.125.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.22.125.187    266
     192.168.20.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.51.1     192.168.51.5     11
     192.168.51.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.51.5    266
     192.168.51.5  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.51.5    266
   192.168.51.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.51.5    266
    192.168.100.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.51.1     192.168.51.5     11
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.51.5    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.42.204.244    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    172.22.125.187    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.51.5    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.42.204.244    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.22.125.187    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.51.1  Default
    192.168.100.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.51.1       1
    100.100.100.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.51.1       1
     192.168.20.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.51.1       1
===========================================================================
```

However whenever I try a traceroute I'm still going out the default route (192.168.51.1).

```
tracert 11.11.121.110

Tracing route to 11.11.121.110 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.51.1
```

I've also tried disabling / renenabling the NIC without any impact.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a route here:

`Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface       Metric`
`11.11.121.110         255.255.255.255    172.125.121.1   172.22.125.187     11`

but you have no route to that gateway 172.125.121.1 except through the Default Route.

But in your comment to longneck you say:

> 172.22.125.1 (gateway)

Did you mess up the syntax and mean for the gateway IP to be 172.22.125.1 instead of 172.125.121.1?

Comment: I'm just about positive that is what I did.. Thanks for the extra set of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have 3 NICs with IP 10.42.204.244/32, 172.22.125.187/24 and 192.168.51.5/24. However, none of those NICs are in the same subnet as 172.125.121.1. A route defined to an IP not in a subnet directly attached to your computer won't be used.

Comment: 172.22.125.187 (server) and 172.22.125.1 (gateway) both have a /24 subnet. That would be directly attached yes?